# How to get the text inside a svg tag labelled tooltip or the text that is displayed when hovering over an icon using selenium and python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, python-3.11

Html snippet:

```
<span class="build-status-icon__outer"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" tooltip="Failed" focusable="false" class="svg-icon "><use href="/jenkins/images/build-status/build-status-sprite.svg#build-status-static"></use></svg></span>
```

I need the status "Failed" which is the tooltip.

for more reference, It's the green icon below on any jenkins job.

Thanks

Got to hover over the icon and saw the status displayed when i ran with headless commented:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynmTy.png)

```
Status = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main-panel']/h1/span[1]"
a = ActionChains(browser)
a.move_to_element(Status).perform()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following in your xpath to jump into svg element:

```
//*[local-name()='svg']
```

Comment: Worked Thanks, when i inspected it just added an "/svg" instead of this.

Comment: yes, it is a trick with the svg, in most cases it won't be found by a simple /svg, so I am happy I helped

Comment: @SundaraRaman You should accept the answer if it has resolved your problem. That's how you thank someone in SO.